# has inconsistent name: expected , but metadata has when install from url by pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv

I am trying to install a package directly from github by
`pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/cikay/public_repo.git@main#egg=public_repo`
command but got\n
`has inconsistent name: expected 'public-repo', but metadata has 'main'`.
If I specify `egg=main` it works. What is wrong? Why I cannot specify any name I would like?

Comment: Expected `public-repo` not `public_repo`

Comment: @ScriptCode When I specify `egg=public-repo` got `has inconsistent name: expected 'public-repo', but metadata has 'main'` the same error.

Comment: Generating metadata for package public-repo produced metadata for project name main. Fix your #egg=public-repo fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The package name should be specified in the setup function.

```
setup(name="package_name")
```